# How to prevent divs from moving when I hover on an element that changes size above it

Tags: css

http://bit.ly/1fVGrBT

Here is my website. When you hover on Problem and move away, the div below it gets pushed up and down. Same  happens for Solution. Any idea or tips how to prevent it from moving?

I think it is moving due to the changed font size and the underline, but I am not sure what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set CSS `line-height` to fix the height for text in `<h3>` tags

Comment: This kinda worked for me, but the div still moves but its quite minimal. Best so far! Thanks!

Comment: try with `line-height:20px`

Answer (score 1):

On hover, you enlarge the text, and thus the container. This pushes the rest of the content down.

3 solutions:

1. Use `transform: scale(1.2);` to enlarge the text. This doesn't affect the flow of the document. Add this to your `element:hover`. Remember to add browser prefixes. Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp)

   Example:

   ```
   #switcher li:hover {
   transform: scale(1.2);
   }
   ```
2. Add a `height` to your navigation. This locks the container height.
3. Add `position: absolute` on either the navigation or the content. This removes them from the document flow, so won't affect each other.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to fix it for me:

```
#switcher {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 30px;
}
```

basically I'm telling the container to not expand more than 30px in height.

Comment: hmm this doesn't seem to work well for me.. Or is max-height not for Chrome?