# How to prevent adjoining elements from moving when increasing border width?

Tags: css

I have a simply layout that consists of boxes.

```css
 .action_box {
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
 }
 .action_box p {
   border: 1px solid black;
   margin-top: 0px;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .action_box:hover {
   border: 2px solid black;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
```

When hovering about one box I want it to get a broader border. Actually it works, but all other boxes are moving away and destroying the website. How can I prevent such behavior? Adding a padding does not achieve this goal.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912335/how-to-prevent-divs-from-moving-when-i-hover-on-an-element-that-changes-size-abo) post and the only possible solution would be to use `position: absolute;`. I'd need to assign individual parameters to each box. Isn't there an easier way, but I would like to use only one class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pretty easy to do actually.  If you don't want to go the absolute position route, you can do it two ways: substitute a box-shadow the increased border if your don't mind the [compatibility compromise](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow) or use `box-sizing:border-box`.  The only problem with `box-sizing:border-box` is that it shifts your content inward (the style rule calculates the total width + padding + border-width in the `width` attribute.  If you set a 5px border to a 100px box, the width is normally 110px to include both left and right borders.  With the `box-sizing` attribute it calculates the border width into the `width` making it 90px wide instead to allow for the 10px of border width).

j08691 already has the box-sizing solution in his answer, so here is the box-shadow method (notice that I only added 1px of box shadow.  This is because the border is still present providing half of the desired width):

```css
 .action_box {
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
 }
 .action_box p {
   border: 1px solid black;
   margin-top: 0px;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .action_box:hover {
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
```

If, however, you want neither of these approaches, there is still the `position:absolute` solution.  For this method, you don't need another class or anything like that.  You can use a pseudo-element instead.  This is probably overkill for what you need, but it is still an option.

```css
 .action_box {
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   position: relative; /* give it some context */
 }
 .action_box p {
   border: 1px solid black;
   margin-top: 0px;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .action_box:hover:after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   border: 2px solid black;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
```

Comment: Accepted answer for a good explanation and for pointing out disadvantages of the `box-sizing` way.

Comment: but box-shadow doesn't work with border-radius right ?

Answer (score 6):

Add `box-sizing:border-box;` to your `.action_box` class:

```css
.action_box {
   width: 300px;
   height: 200px;
   border: 1px solid black;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
 }
 .action_box p {
   border: 1px solid black;
   margin-top: 0px;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .action_box:hover {
   border: 2px solid black;
   cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
<div class="action_box">asdasds</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution could be using `box-shadow` instead `border`:

```
.action_box:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px black;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/aja8wn7n/)

Note: With this solution the inner content don't move neither :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to add a `transparent` border to the element before hand, so it already occupies the space and will not move when the `border-color` is changed.